# Pass additional login parameters from custom WebFlux loginForm

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I have implemented a Custom `ReactiveAuthenticationManager` to work with my `formLogin`.

```
@Bean
public ReactiveAuthenticationManager reactiveAuthenticationManager() {
    return new ReactiveAuthenticationManagerAdapter(this::authenticate);
}

private Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            userId, password, authorities);
```

}

This works fine, the `authenticate` function is called at the right time. However I must now send in an additional parameter from the login form. I have been able to create a custom login form which send the extra parameter to the endpoint but how do I include it in the `Authentication` object I get in `authenticate`???

I found [this](http://herogtech.com/pass-extra-parameter-spring-security-login-page/) example that looks straight forward in the implementation but its for Spring MVC and I need to do it in WebFlux.

UPDATE:

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/login/**")
            .permitAll()
            .pathMatchers("/**")
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .authenticationSuccessHandler(new RedirectServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler("/"))
            .authenticationFailureHandler(this::onAuthenticationFailure)
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler("/bye"));

    return http.build();
}
```

#### Update

I have some progress now. By not using the default `formLogin` on `ServerHttpSecurity` but instead using my own `WebFilter` that extends `AuthenticationWebFilter` im able to do what I want. The issue im getting now is that I dont have a default entry point and also its hard to know if im missing something else magically that the `ServerHttpSecurity` class does for me.

Comment: Can you post also your configuration for the `SecurityWebFilterChain`? What you want is possible but it will take a little bit of configuration.

Comment: i have updated with the requested code

Answer (score 1):

I try to do it more elegant but it would be far more work. So I settle for this insed. You have to build your SecurityWebFiler chain just like you do. But after you create it you have to find this `AuthenticationWebFilter` it is a web filter responsible for creation of `authentication` object. And set your own authentication converter.

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
       http.authorizeExchange()
           .anyExchange().authenticated()
           .and()
           .formLogin()
       ;

    final SecurityWebFilterChain build = http.build();

    build.getWebFilters().collectList().subscribe(
            webFilters -> {
                for (WebFilter filter : webFilters){
                    if(filter instanceof AuthenticationWebFilter){
                        AuthenticationWebFilter awf = (AuthenticationWebFilter) filter;
                        awf.setAuthenticationConverter(new CustomHttpBasicAuthenticationConverter());
                    }
                }
            }
    );

    return build;
}
```

Example Of the `HttpBasicAuthenticationConverter`. To be honest I just copied it from the spring source. Hope that helps.

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.function.Function;

public class CustomHttpBasicAuthenticationConverter implements Function<ServerWebExchange, Mono<Authentication>> {

private String usernameParameter = "username";
private String passwordParameter = "password";

@Override
public Mono<Authentication> apply(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    return exchange.getFormData()
            .map( data -> createAuthentication(data));
}

private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken createAuthentication(
        MultiValueMap<String, String> data) {
    String username = data.getFirst(this.usernameParameter);
    String password = data.getFirst(this.passwordParameter);
    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
}

public void setUsernameParameter(String usernameParameter) {
    Assert.notNull(usernameParameter, "usernameParameter cannot be null");
    this.usernameParameter = usernameParameter;
}

public void setPasswordParameter(String passwordParameter) {
    Assert.notNull(passwordParameter, "passwordParameter cannot be null");
    this.passwordParameter = passwordParameter;
}
}
```